# Upgrade TFS 2010 to 2015 FOREIGN KEY constraint error

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS 2015.

Before the actual upgrade I want to do a test upgrade, meaning leave the 2010 alive.

I backed up the databases and restored them on a new sever. Then I run the TFS upgrade.

When it finishes I get the following error:

> Could not drop object 'Constants' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to contact Microsoft for support on this.  We recently upgraded from 2010 to 2015 but didn't have this issue.  I suspect someone customized your TFS instance and it is conflicting with the migration script.

If you use CodedUI tests [this post](http://dotnetcatch.com/2015/10/01/tfs-2010-to-2015-upgrade-codedui-feature-test-builds/) may help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The updated failed so I haven't got around to set up builds and test yet. I do not no of any customization done on the tfs database but I will have a look